# Is there a way to inherit the Moodle quiz module?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I've been tasked with developing a custom quiz module that functions exactly like the core quiz module but with some UI modifications. The issue is that our users still need to use the core quiz module as well.

Is there a way to create a new activity that inherits all of the quiz module?

Or alternatively, is there a way to conditionally override the quiz renderer based on a custom quiz setting that can be changed in the core quiz settings?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend the whole module, however, what you can do is copy quiz module in your custom folder and make all classes extend mod/quiz classes. Rename all requires too to point to your module. Don't forget to put dependency in version.php file